# How to override the default variable light-theme variable in bootstrap 5.3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use the new `theme` feature available in bootstrap 5.3. I compiled bootstrap locally using the SASS compiler. I want to change the default background-color to `#EDF4FA` when the current theme used is `light` and set the `--bs-card-bg` to white.

I tried the following

```
@include color-mode(light) {
    --bs-body-color: #EDF4FA;
    --bs-body-color-rgb: #{to-rgb(#EDF4FA)};
    --bs-card-bg: var(--bs-white);
}
```

But that does not seems to work. The `--bs-body-color` is set as expected. However, the `--bs-card-bg` does not change.

Here is the css rules from the browser. As you can see at the bottom `--bs-card-bg: var(--bs-white)` has a line through it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there is couple ways to do this.

##### Using variable

```scss
@include color-mode(light) {
    .card {
        --bs-card-bg: var(--bs-white);
    }
}
```

##### Using variable

```scss
@include color-mode(light) {
    .card {
        background-color: var(--bs-white);
    }
}
```